# Accessing index of list after instantiation

Tags: c#, list, exception

I have created a list using:

```
List<int> foo = new List<int>();
```

I need to be able to insert values into any index after I create this. If I have

```
foo[325] = 55;
```

an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown with the following details:

```
Index must be within the bounds of the List.
Parameter name: index
```

What must I do in order to correct this? I could fill the list with dummy values and then access the indices after the list is filled, but that seems like a messy solution.

Comment: I am sending a command to a bunch of devices, which do not always respond in the order that they receive the command. Thus, I cant always use the .add function. I need to determine the correct index based off of the device. This means that sometimes I will need to access indices out of order. I am using certain functions that are only in the List<T>, which is why I did not really want to use an array.

Comment: I would agree with the comments below that you don't want a list here.  You should use a Dictionary that way you take advantage of the [Key, Value] pairing.  Since order is unknown you can easily find the what you need using the dictionary and won't have to do any loops or LINQ queries to get the data back

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am going to do. I should have thought of that in the first place!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a List<> isn't the correct datatype to use for storage.

If you used a `Dictionary<int, int>()` you can just maintain the indexes you wish:

```
Dictionary<int, int> foo = new Dictionary<int, int>();

foo.Add(idx, val);
```

And to retrieve:

```
var Value = foo[idx];
```

If you plan on actually using every single index, you'd be better off doing:

```
List<int> foo = Enumerable.Range(0, MaxNumber).ToList();
```

To pre-fill the list.

Answer (score 2):

System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary  class might be better if you really need random access

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use an array rather than a list. But you would have to specify a size.

```
var foo = new int[500];
foo[325] = 55;
```